Redirecting Angular application to home page after authenticating with AWS cognito HostedUI
I have developed an angular application which uses AWS cognito hosted UI for authorization.
https://testapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=3xxxxxxxxco8ixxxi8&response_type=token&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phone+profile&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fadmin%2Fhome
Once I login successfully it redirects me to localhost:4200/home as per the redirection URL setup in
enter image description here
I created a s3 bucket and copied all dist content on S3. I also setup domain, cloudfront with s3 and eventually when I hit my domain url, it launches the authentication page but after that it doesn't work for obvious reason that I have redirected my application to localhost. But if I change it to https://customdomain.com/admin/home it doesn't work as well/
How to fix this problem?
I tried redirecting to localhost:4200/admin/home which works fine but I want to redirect to https://customdomain.com/admin/home
